# How to access os clipboard using Emacs + Evil

Tags: microsoft-windows, evil, copy-paste

How can i yank to/from windows clipboard when using:

- Windows 7 (x64)
- GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x64)
- Evil 1.0.9
- and having `(setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)` in my `.emacs`? (I put this line there because i didn't want vim changes (<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, etc) to clobber my os clipboard.

I tried <kbd>"+p</kbd>, <kbd>"*p</kbd>, <kbd>"+y</kbd>, <kbd>"*y</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL+Y</kbd> but it doesn't work. When i run `:registers` it doesn't even show `+` or `*` registers.

To clarify: I want Emacs to behave like Vim when copying/yanking to/from different registers, without clobbering os clipboard with every text changing command. In particular:

- <kbd>yy</kbd> - should NOT yank text to os clipboard (only to `0` register)
- <kbd>"+yy</kbd> - should yank text to os clipboard
- <kbd>dd</kbd> - should NOT clobber os clipboard
- <kbd>cw</kbd> - shold NOT clobber os clipboard
- etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disabled the clipboard integration with:

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)
```

Then you should still be able to copy and paste using the + register of evil. If you still want to integrate with the clipboard without evil, you could use this function to paste:

```
(defun paste-from-clipboard ()
  (interactive)
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
  (yank)
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil))
```

and this one for copyping:

```
(defun copy-to-clipboard()
  (interactive)
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
  (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil))
```

Then bind `copy-to-clipboard` to `M-w` and `paste-from-clipboard` to `C-y`, or other keybinding of your choice.

**Edit:** I'm running Archlinux. Can't say if this'll work on Windows.

Comment: Under Linux Mint the ```(setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)``` is enough too because there are ```+``` and ```*``` registers to work with os clipboard, not under windows unfortunately.

Comment: I tried your custom function (in windows) with evil plugin and ```(setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)```: The yanking FROM os clipboard works as it should, but i can't yank the selection TO os clipboard (with bindings ```(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-y") 'paste-from-clipboard)``` and ```(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-y") 'paste-from-clipboard)```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean, `paste-from-clipboard` will only paste from clipboard. You'll need another function to copy to clipboard. I edited the question to added a `copy-to-clipboard` function. Please try if it works

Comment: I wrongly thought the ```yank``` function copies to and from os clipboard (based on the presence of visual selection). Your other function does what i want, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip

it cover ALL the use cases on Mac/Linux/Windows/Cygwin.

More specifically, for copy&paste, there are only two commands:

```
simpleclip-get-contents
simpleclip-set-contents
```

Feel free to assign short keys.

Comment: This is wonderful, it simplifies interaction with the clipboard drastically.

Comment: Agreed that this is a wonderful little tool, and still working beautifully in 2022 (updated as recently as 2020).

Answer (score 0):

For people trying this on macOs, I used [pbcopy.el](https://melpa.org/#/pbcopy). I realize this question was for Windows, but I spent a lot of time trying to get it to work on macOs, so sharing what I used.

To use your system’s clipboard on copy, cut and paste, install [pbcopy](https://melpa.org/#/pbcopy)

To install it, run

1. `M-x package-install`
2. Press the return key
3. provide `pbcopy.el` as the package to install
4. Press the return key
5. inside your config file, add:

```lisp
(require 'pbcopy)
(turn-on-pbcopy)
```

6. restart emacs